# Closure of Y in one-point compactification

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, compactification

I have some trouble with following problem:
Let X be a locally compact Hausdorff space where $X^+=X \cup \{\infty\}$ is its one-point compcatification and $Y \subseteq X$. Compute the closure of Y in $X^+$ in terms of its closure in X.
**This is what I have so far:**
The adherent points of Y which are elements of X are still adherent points of Y in $X^+$, so the question is whether the point at the infinity is an adherent point of Y in $X^+$ or not. Consider two cases:

- Case 1: The set Y is a subset of some compact K included in X.
- Case 2: Case 1 does not hold, that is, for any compact K included in
  X there are points of Y which are not in K.

**Heres what I need help with:**

1. I Think I just need to decide what happens with the point at the infinity in each case, but I am a little confused about that part?
2. Is the start correct?

Answer (score 1):

$\infty$ belongs to the closure of $Y$ in $X^{+}$ iff $K^{c}$ intersects $Y$ for every compact set $K$ iff $Y$ is not  a subset of any compact set $K$ in $X$.  This is so iff $Y$ is not relatively compact set in $X$.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am a little unsure still, Can you maybe explain a little what you mean?

Comment: @EllySanders Open sets contatining $\infty$ are complements of comapct sets in $X$. $\infty$ belongs to the closure of $Y$ in $X^{+}$ if and only if every open set containing $\infty$ intersects $Y$. I am just putting these two facts together.